# heroku - Couldn't find that process type (web)

Tags: heroku

I am following the tutorial [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#deploy-the-app)

but I got the error

```
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

when doing

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

I followed the solution [here](https://help.heroku.com/W23OAFGK/why-am-i-seeing-couldn-t-find-that-process-type-when-trying-to-scale-dynos)

by delete the buildpack and use `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python`

But the error still happend

and for buildpacks:

```
heroku buildpacks
=== teaching-system Buildpack URL
heroku/python
```

it seem to be correct

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I did to past this error in Django. It's on Windows10

- Add Procfile -in the same folder where you have git, manage.py

```
Procfile
-------------------------------
web: gunicorn <django-root-name(containing wsgi)>.wsgi --log-file -
```

- Installing gunicorn(for later use)
  `>python -m pip install gunicorn`
- Clearing BuildPacks & fixing them
  `>heroku buildpacks:clear`
  `>heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python`
- commit(empty-commit) & push
  `>git commit --allow-empty -m "Adjust push heroku master"`
  `git push heroku master`
  That's what made me pass this `scaling dyno..` blah blah

**Update:**

- For local development, add following file

```
Procfile.windows
------------------------------------------
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
```

Comment: This problem happens because I haven't install gunicorn. I asked this question a year ago and finally solved it by installing gunicorn module. Both mac and win10 works.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have a Procfile that is in the same directory as your Pipfile and Pipfile.lock files.

I'm using django and in Procfile I had:

```py
#Procfile
web: gunicorn <my_project_name>.wsgi --log-file -
```

Install gunicorn if you haven't already. I had the same error and spent a long time trying to resolve it so I hope this helps. The syntax will change depending on what framework and language you're using, but the idea should be similar.

Answer (score 2):

in Django,i solved creating the next files:

```
--------------------------------------------
**Procfile.windows** :
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
-------------------------------------------
**requirements.txt** :
django
gunicorn
django-heroku
------------------------------------------
**runtime.txt** :
python-3.7.7
-------------------------------------------------------
**Procfile** :
web: gunicorn <name of my main folder app>.wsgi --log-file -
----------------------
**.env** :
TIMES=2
----------------------
```

and after just do a commit to local repository,so the steps will be:

*
    heroku login
    heroku create
    git commit -m "gogogo heroku"
    git push heroku master
    heroku ps:scale web=1
    heroku open

*

Comment: That's what I'm looking for 8 hours

Answer (score 0):

It may have happened if you have modified your Procfile or renamed it after pushing to Heroku master. If so, you can try to make it work by rebuilding the index.

In my case this worked:

1. remove cached files (only the paths are removed from the index, not the real files!!!)

   git rm -r --cached .
2. add all files to the index

   git add .
3. commit

   git commit -m "hopefully fixed error"
4. run rest of the heroku commands again

worked for me! hope it does for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Link-only answers are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248627) as they low-effort and low-value. They are also subject to "link rot", often becoming useless as links break in the future. Please edit your answer and include the main points directly in your question. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem a few week later in another Flask project

It was caused by loosing library: gunicorn in current virtual environment